# How to add my existing maven gwt/gae project into Enterprise Application project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, gwt

How do I add my existing GWT/GAE maven project into a new EAR project in Eclipse? So my first step is creating an EAR project with target runtime of GAE, then after that I want to add my existing GAE/GWT maven project as a default module in it. How can I do this? I only see an option to add dynamic web application module.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using maven but I'm having a similar problem.  I've recorded it here http://screencast.com/t/qYXmgigdjS (5 minutes).  I'm talking to Google Platform Support to see if I can get it resolved.